# How to make a behavior of a variable final when its obtained only once through a setter

Tags: java, design-patterns, final

Assume this imaginary scenario where a variable value is obtained only through a setter but once obtained it cannot be modified.

```
class Foo {
   Bar bar;

   public void setBarOnlyOnce(Bar bar) {
      this.bar = bar
   }  
}
```

Now since I dont want to change the value of bar, once being set, I would add a check in setter.

```
 public void setBarOnlyOnce(Bar bar) {
         if (bar != null) {
             this.bar = bar
         }
   }
```

Quite an obvious handicap is that class is hard to maintain, as anyone can add a method to this class  which can modify value of bar negligently.

Is there some link/guidelines/design patterns instructing how to deal with those variables which you want to be final, but cant keep it final as they would be obtained only through setter ?

Comment: It begs the question: why not pass it to a constructor?

Answer (score 3):

One can implement a property wrapper to control field access:

```
class ImmutableProperty<T>{

    private T value;

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        if (this.value == null) {
            this.value = value;
        }  else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Once set, ImmutableProperty cannot be modified");
        }
    }
}
```

use it like this to prevent unwanted modifications:

```
private final ImmutableProperty<String> name = new ImmutableProperty<>();
...
name.set("I can do that!");
name.set("But here I'm going to fail(");
```

This approach prevents anyone from reassigning `name` variable itself and clearly expresses your initial intention for this variable to be immutable.

**EDIT:**

This implementation is a bit smarter and allow null values to be set if necessary:

```
class ImmutableProperty<T>{

    private boolean set;
    private T value;

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        if (!set) {
            set = true;
           this.value = value;
        }  else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Once set, ImmutableProperty cannot be modified");
        }
    }
}
```

and this one also pretends to be thread-safe:

```
class ImmutableProperty<T> {

    class DataHolder {
        final T value;

        DataHolder(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private final DataHolder defaultValue = new DataHolder(null);
    private final AtomicReference<DataHolder> holder = new AtomicReference<>(defaultValue);

    public T get() {
        return holder.get().value;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        if (!holder.compareAndSet(defaultValue, new DataHolder(value))) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Once set, ImmutableProperty cannot be modified");
        }
    }
}
```

Choose the one that better suits your needs.

Comment: Not thread-safe, and doesn't allow null as a valid value (which it could well be)

Comment: Although your concern about null values is perfectly valid, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thread safety is an implied need, since you want to prevent race conditions from setting the value twice. If thread safety is not needed, you don't need anything special.

Comment: That looks like a valid point. I've provided thread-safe version as well for the OP to choose the most suitable one

Comment: Pssst: `AtomicMarkableReference` ;)

Comment: Ha, you got me) Just at the moment I got my reinvented wheel tuned and polished. The only advantage my implementation still have is a more self-explanatory name: 'ImmutableProperty' probably is more obvious to the reader, than 'AtomicMarkableReference'. Take my +1 anyway.

Comment: It it makes you feel any better, that *is* a very shiny wheel :)

Answer (score 2):

An [AtomicMarkableReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicMarkableReference.html) does exactly what you want and is also thread safe in case that is a concern:

```
class Foo {
    private final AtomicMarkableReference<Bar> bar = 
        new AtomicMarkableReference<Bar>(null, false);

    public boolean setBar(Bar b) {
        return bar.compareAndSet(null, b, false, true);
    }

    public boolean barIsSet() {
        return bar.isMarked();
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar.getReference();
    }
}
```

This uses a CAS (Compare And Swap) operation that prevents the reference from being set unless the existing reference value is `null` and the marker is `false`. The first call of the method invalidates at least one of those conditions; by using the `AtomicMarkableReference` instead of a plain `AtomicReference`, it covers the case of `null` being explicitly set.

**Edit to add:** This returns false if the set fails; you could choose to throw an `IllegalStateException` if you wanted to be more forceful about it.

```
public void setBar(Bar b) {
    if (!bar.compareAndSet(null, b, false, true)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You can only set bar once");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no better way to do this using regular Java that achieves your goal:

- It might be possible to implement the "set if not null" behaviour via AspectJ or similar, but I don't think you can *prevent* someone adding a method that modifies the variable "negligently".
- The same goes for inventing wrapper classes like the suggested `ImmutableProperty` class.  Ultimately someone can "negligently" rewrite that code; e.g. remove the `final` on `name` and assign a different `ImmutableProperty`.  Besides, this kind of thing makes your code harder to read and modify for everyone ... not just the "negligent" developers.

The only possible changes / improvements I can suggest are the obvious ones:

- declare `bar` as `private` and provide a getter method, and
- use a separate flag in the case where `null` is a (properly documented!) meaningful value for `getBar()`.

---

But to be honest, you shouldn't be trying to stop future developers from making specific changes to your source code ... either "negligently" or otherwise:

- Anything that you try can be defeated by either an (ugly) workaround, or simply rewriting your code to remove the roadblocks you have added.  (That may cost them the pain of an incompatible API change ... but >>you<< will be the person they blame!)
- It is possible that there will be good reasons to make the changes that you are trying to prevent.  Reasons that you haven't anticipated; e.g. your codebase is being repurposed.

IMO the best strategy is to do the normal things (like declaring things private, final, etc), put comments in the code warning against ... whatever it is you are trying to avoid ... but don't put in any *extra* impediments.  Treat programmers who are going to use and maintain your code as adults.  If necessary, deal with programmers who are inclined to code "negligently" by using normal software engineering quality management strategies such as peer code reviews.

Comment: and what if someone wants to set the value to null (as the final value)? I think the null test is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Bohemian - that is true.  A better idea might be to have a separate boolean that says whether the variable has been set yet.

Comment: +1 for sane engineering rather than building a space shuttle for no reason.

Comment: That was my thought too. Make it volatile and put some synch in and it would fly thread-safely. Anyway, sage advice +1

Comment: @Bohemian - I wouldn't do that ... unless the class was *required* to be thread-safe.  (IMO, that counts as "space shuttle" design.)

Comment: I'm going with `AtomicReference` myself as the solution :-D

Comment: Yeah, but thread safety seems like an obvious implicit requirement - this sounds a but like a "lazy final" pattern. If not needed to be threadsafe, for example use constructor and final, and throw away the current object if you need to set once by using a copy constructor with the value to set. I just felt that the fact this question was asked meant there must be more to it. @Brian AtomicReference sounds good :)

Comment: Yeah - see my answer. Only thing it doesn't cover is setting `null` but that's easily solved if need be.

Comment: Ha, actually, AtomicMarkableReference does all of the above. I think I win :-D

Comment: Ermm ... how can you infer it is an "obvious" requirement?  There is ZERO meaningful context in the question to make any inferences.  Your inference is really a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first thing that comes into my mind is that others don't have to work on Foo class. They should subclass it, so they will be forced to use your `public final void setBarOnlyOnce(Bar bar)` method, for setting `private Bar bar;`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using constructor initializing a final field?

```
class Foo {
   final Bar bar;

   public Foo(Bar bar) {
      this.bar = bar
   }  
}
```